# Assigning class dynamically to a generic list

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create a function that would take an object of a class and then the function will use that object to retrieve it class and use it as a model for XML parsing. The function looks like this:

```
myClass myClassObject=new myClass();
List aList = parseXMLtoList(stringBuffer.toString(),myClassObject);

private List parseXMLtoList(String xmlString,Object modelClassObject) {
    List<modelClassObject.getClass()> xmlList = new ArrayList(); //modelClassObject cannot be resolved to a type
...
```

But when I try to use reflecting to given class dynamically it gives me this error: `modelClassObject cannot be resolved to a type`

How can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Don't think you can implement it. Types of collections as other such stuff is for compile time only. So just use List.

Answer (score 0):

You must use generics like this:

```
MyClass myClassObject= new MyClass();
List<MyClass> aList = parseXMLtoList("<some_xml/>", myClassObject);


private static <T> List<T> parseXMLtoList(String xmlString, T modelClassObject) {
    List<T> xmlList = new ArrayList<T>();
```

You can restrain the type that can be used by adding this in the generic definition:

```
private static <T extends MyClass>
```

More on generics : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/